# How does UIViewController's automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets work anyway?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
```

I set that to yes. I think it's yes by default.

Then when I check the inset this is what I got:
NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets(self.tableView.contentInset): {0, 0, 0, 0}

I thought it should be set up in a way that incorporate the navigationBar and statusbar. So what happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I know

[automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)

> allows the view controller to adjust its scroll view insets in
>   response to the screen areas consumed by the status bar, navigation
>   bar, and toolbar or tab bar

- works on the view which is direct subview ([someone says it must be
  the first subview](http://www.codelord.net/2013/10/18/adapting-scroll-views-to-ios-7/)) of the View Controller 's view
- this view must be a ScrollView subclass
- the View Controller is embedded in Navigation Controller or TabBar
  Controller
- `edgesForExtendedLayout` is `UIEdgeRectTop` (if you want the ScrollView
  subclass view to be behind the top bar), UIEdgeRectBottom (if you want
  the ScrollView subclass view to be behind the bottom bar)

The code below replicates what `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` does when `edgesForExtendedLayout = UIEdgeRectTop`

```
self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0, 0, 0);
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -self.topLayoutGuide.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your UIVIewController's `edgesForExtendedLayout` value. If you want content to appear AFTER top, set `edgesForExtendedLayout' = UIRectEdgeNone (or UIRectEdgeRight | UIRectEdgeLeft | UIRectEdgeBottom, you just don't want to include`UIRectEdgeTop`)

Comment: I left that at default. What's the default anyway?

Comment: Setting edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone will shift the main view AFTER top. I want to arrange the inset of scrollview. That's 2 different things. I know how to do the former one.